# Is there a built in way to hide a file in Wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

The company I work for has recently taken to generating MSI files with Wix. We're at the tail end of the process, but there's one more thing they need me to do.

We have an XML file with a snapshot of what binaries have gone into the install. However, the customers we deliver to will get somewhat confused about an extra useless file in the install.

Most everything that comes up when I search for 'Wix' and 'hide file' is focused on removing or deleting the files after install. I just need to hide this sucker though.

Is there a way to hide the file through HEAT or something? I can modify the file element in the WXS using XSL or Powershell if need be. Or do I need to resort to a custom action that calls cmd.exe to hide it?

Comment: You can pass an XSL transform to heat to either remove the File (and Component and ComponentRef) or add the hidden attribute.

Comment: (You do realize that an MSI file is a database that lists all the files. You don't need to diff snapshots to compute what it happened to install on one test system.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try setting the file element's `hidden` attribute to `yes`. Taken from [here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html):

> Set to yes in order to have the file's hidden attribute set when it is installed on the target machine.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! Worked like a charm!